# How do I modify one speific element in a string array in c#?

Tags: c#

I am a just beginning to learn c# so this is probably a really basic question. I created a string array: string[] classList = new string[25]; which I populated with student names. I need to modify one name (one element of the string).

Answer (score 2):

Strings are **immutable** so strictly speaking, you cannot modify them.

You can however, replace one of your element references:

```
classList[20] = "New Student";
```

Functions like `String.Replace` can help as well in generating the new string, but you haven't specified *how* you want to change the element.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the index of the name you want to modify, you can just do:

```
int indexOfNameToModify = 14;
string modifiedName = "John";
classList[indexOfName] = modifiedName;
```

If you don't know the index but you know the name, then you can search for the name:

```
string nameToModify = "Jim";
string modifiedName = "John";

for (int i = 0; i < classList.Length; i++)
{
    // Remove the StringComparison argument if you want to do case-sensitive comparison
    if (classList[i].Equals(nameToModify, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        classList[i] = modifiedName;

        // Break if you only want to modify the first one found
        break; 
    }
}
```